# Video trim after recording ios 10

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios10, ios11

I would like to be able to trim a video after recording or selecting it from the photo library. I use `videoMaximumDuration` to limit the time and that works like a charm but when a video is too long, on iOS 10 the trim selector doesn't shows. I tried the same on iOS 11 and it works.

How can I fix this for iOS 10?

This is my code.

```
func startCameraFromViewController(viewController: UIViewController, withDelegate delegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate, sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) -> Bool {
    let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
    cameraController.delegate = delegate
    cameraController.sourceType = sourceType
    cameraController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as NSString as String]
    cameraController.allowsEditing = true
    cameraController.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0

    present(cameraController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return true
}
```

This is what happens on ios 10.[image]

And this is on ios 11.[image]

Comment: Same problem here  did you found any solution?

Comment: In IOS11 the trim bar doesnt work on the left side. only on the right side i can trim. seams like touch is not working. same app on IOS10 is ok.